# Appending data to a mat file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a mat file with some data and i want to add additional data at the end of file whenever a function is called. How can i do it? By save  -append my existing data is overwritten. But for me data should not be overwritten. Reply as early as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You've given no information about the type of data you are storing, but I suspect you might be trying to append values to an array which is stored in a file using `-append`; however, `-append` only adds *new variables* to a file.  If you save a variable with the same name, it will overwrite it.  Instead, just do the append manually:

I'll assume that we are talking about a 1xn vector, you can adjust the concatenation step as necessary.

```
x = load('myfile');
x = [ x newX ];
save('myfile', 'x');
```

Comment: thanks for response. I tried this and My mat file has one matrix of two dimensional. So I tried to add at the end as below
>> x=load('hashes.mat');
>> y=x.HashTable;  % HashTable is name of matrix
>> y(end+1,:)=hash; % hash is another matrix
but i'm getting an error like this
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
how can i add my new data ??

Comment: Do it the way I did.  I'm assuming from your code that `hash` is nx1, so do this: `y = [ y; hash ]`.

Comment: My HashTable dimensions are 20 X 10476 and i want to add after 20 rows.